# beginner python on mac osx 10.8

Tags: python, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm learning programming and have been working with Ruby and ROR, but feel I like Python's language better for learning programming. Although I see the beauty of Ruby and Rails, I feel I need a language more easy to learn programming concepts, thus Python. However, I can't seem to find a community online or offline that work on Apple osx; mostly seems to be PC people for Python. What I like about Ruby is that there is a lot of books, communities, etc, and they tend to have a good amount of Mac resources. Would someone be able to point me to an google groups, forums, etc for beginner Python programming that may have tutorials, or help for people running on Mountain Lion? I'm feeling a little frustrated and caught between the Ruby Vs. Python paradigm, and just want some mac specific resources working with latest Python and eventually Django.

Thanks for any help you may be able to offer!

Comment: There are [MacOS installers](http://python.org/download/). What specifically are you having trouble with? Learning Python should be basically the same on every platform.

Comment: Python and Django should abstract enough away from the OS that you don't have to care what platform you're on. Start here http://www.learnpython.org/

Comment: Anna & Aesthete  Thank you. That makes sense to me.

Comment: Python is a beautiful language. Good luck and enjoy!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.8 comes bundled with Python 2.7.2 found at `/usr/bin/python`. Generally in the Python world your operating system is abstracted away, so there aren't that many OS-specific communities. Apple fully embraces Python, however, and you can even write fully native applications using Python.

My suggestions to get you started would be to:

- Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) - This is an open source package installer for Mac OS X, inspired by Debian's [apt-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) or RedHat's [yum](http://yum.baseurl.org/). This will allow you to easily install many of the system-level dependencies like database servers, NoSQL servers, system libraries, and so on. You will inevitably be required to install this stuff as time goes by, so it's best to have the right tool for the job!
- Install [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) - The Python package installer. You won't regret it. This will allow you to easily manage external Python packages.
- Check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It's quite good, but also assumes you have at least basic understanding of programming.
- Check out [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/), a free e-Book by Zed Shaw, which assumes no prior programming experience and is very, very easy to follow.

These should keep you busy for a while!!

Comment: I'd add that you shouldn't use `pip`, `easy_install`, `python setup.py install` to install packages into system python as a root (sooner or later it'll break stuff.) i.e., `--user` or virtualenv should be used instead. Only programs such as `homebrew` should be allowed to touch system installation.

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion, but that also adds a lot more complexity which might be a bit daunting to newcomers. In my opinion there isn't anything wrong with using the default Python version, so long as you **don't mess with ANYTHING that comes bundled with the OS**. In 10.8, they've further simplified where your external `site-packages` go: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. I'll take it!

Comment: `alias pip_install="pip install --user"` and you're ready to go. Or [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) might simplify working with many virtualenvs.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thank you so much for giving me a thoughtful answer. I've been getting pulled between python and ruby and it just seemed to me that ruby was more community, but I think it has to do with being more vocal. I've started working on python on an old mac while my new one HD is being replaced, and I'm enjoying the "cleanliness" of the syntax. Thanks again, and I will try your suggestion with homebrew.  ---> @ jathanism: thank you for your insight!

Comment: I'll echo the first commenter's sentiment that installing packages into the system-wide Python environment is bad practice. In older versions of OSX it can break things, but more importantly, it makes it hard to track project dependencies. Virtual environments are a *requirement* for anything remotely serious in Python - and Python 3.3 has built-in support for them via [pyvenv](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html).

Comment: Hey guys, I was trying to setup django framework. Unfortunately, I remove /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages from my machine. I update the homebrew or brew. But also it didn't get /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. I also try to reinstall but its not working. So, I make director site=packages inside /Library/Python/2.7/ but its giving me problem. will yo please suggest me what to do next or reinstall system python2.7.